# Difference Between 修理 and 直す

Tags: word-choice

Although both means repair, but I am not able to understand the differences between them.
Is it that, when human efforts are involved in repair its called **直す** and when it is being repaired by any other means is called **修理**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are many, many examples of this kind. There are always different ways of saying the same thing. The 漢語 (Chinese-derived word) plus する verb is often the more formal version, whereas the simple native Japanese word is less formal. When comparing 車を直す and 車を修理する, 直す and 修理する both mean "to repair", but the latter sounds a tad more technical, but probably only because it is more formal. It's something like

> 車を修理する
> to perform a car maintenance operation
>
> 車を直す
> to repair the car

but both can involve human efforts. In general, however, なおす means more than just 修理する:

> [椅子]{いす}を**直して**ください
> **Put** the chair **back** where it was.
>
> 病気を**[治]{なお}す**
> to **cure** an ailment
>
> 作り**直す**
> to **re**make
>
> この文章を**直して**ください
> Please **correct** this sentence.

(See Tsuyoshi Ito's comment below.)

Comment: I would add that this is very similar to English. A lot of Latin derived words are the equivalent if jukugo (of Chinese origin).

Comment: I am afraid that this answer is either misleading or incorrect.  修理する has a more specific meaning than 直す, and it is not just a more formal way of saying the same thing.  For example, we can say 間違った答えを直す (correct a wrong answer), but we cannot say 間違った答えを修理する.  (See also istrasci’s answer.)  This happens in many cases: native Japanese words tend to have a more general meaning and be less formal, and Sino-Japanese words tend to have a more specific meaning and be more formal.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto There was just a question about this (with an answer from you) about whether 物 and 者 are different words. I hope you agree that 修理する and 直す are very close in meaning, when one compares 車を直す and 車を修理する. (In the sense that 車を直す often just means 車を修理する.) But of course 直す can mean much more, which I tried to hint at by mentioning 治す. I guess, you are right, though, in that なおす, even written as 直す, means more than 修理する. I'll edit my answer a little.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but isn't the chair example Kansaiben? I always thought that 直す used to mean 片付ける was Kansaiben?

Comment: @Jeemusu I guess you are right. I was trying to come up with an example that came close to EDICT's definition "(4) to replace/to put back as it was". But people from 関東 seem to use 直す in a narrower sense (closer to 修理する) than people from 関西 (or 九州), who use it an all sorts of ways, including 片付ける, which probably comes closer to 直す as "to straighten".

Comment: Well, if you look at a particular example in which 直す and 修理する are almost synonymous, then they are almost synonymous….  That is exactly what we mean by “修理する has a more specific meaning than 直す.”  I think that my point still stands: the most important difference between 直す and 修理する is not the difference in formality, but the difference in meanings.

Comment: I would add that whether 直す and 治す are the same word or not is irrelevant to my point.  The cases written as 直す alone are more general than 修理する (even if we ignore dialectal meanings and the meanings in compound words, by the way).

Comment: By the way, it is more suitable to refer to istrasci’s answer than to my comment, because istrasci explained the difference between the meanings of 直す and 修理する, whereas I just pointed out that there is some difference between their meanings.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto I understood the body of the question to be "When 直す and 修理する are used in the sense of _to repair_, what is the difference between them?", which I answered with "There is no notable difference in meaning." In particular, the conjecture of the OP, that one involved human efforts and the other doesn't, is false. You are suggesting I should answer "What is the difference between 直す and 修理する?" I see little point in editing my answer to duplicate istrasci's answer.

Comment: If I misunderstood the question, I hope the OP will mark as accepted answer the answer, which answers his question.

Answer (score 10):

`修理` means "fix/repair" and almost, if not always refers to fixing something that is physically broken.

`直す` can also mean "fix" as in something broken, but has more metaphorical uses.  "Fix" as in correct a mistake (often seen as a compound verb `〜なおす`: `書き直す` to rewrite); "fix" as in straighten out, put right, etc.;  "Fix" as in change/alter (a plan, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

`直す` is a verb, and `修理` is a noun.

`修理` can be made into a verb by adding `する`, as in `修理する`, or into an adjective by adding `の`, but it's still a noun at heart. Likewise, `直す` can also be made into a noun by adding `こと`, but it is still a verb. Just because a language allows you to modify words into different forms shouldn't trick you into thinking they are the same thing. They have different grammatical purposes and usages.

So `直す` is "***to*** fix", whereas `修理` is "***a*** repair".